# MC Journey - Data binding in a "one-to-many" scenario

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, databinding

I'm having difficulty updating a Sales Cloud field with the correct data via a journey, using the Object Activity. The field mapping is updating the field in the Sales Cloud CRM field with the following data binding:

`{{Contact.Attribute."DE_NAME"."DE_FIELD"}}`

This data binding references the contact, however in the referenced data extension there are multiple records for the contact.

Is there a data binding script that can reference both the contact **and** a secondary ID so that I can access the correct record? The secondary ID is available in the Journey data.

The above referenced data ***must*** be contact data (as per the use of `{{Contact.Attribute`), not journey data, as the data will likely update throughout the life of the journey.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I am not sure if `switch` is supported in this data binding version:

let's say the second matching key you want is from Journey DE field called `fieldC` that needs to match Contact DE `fieldB`, below script is for easy read, remove line breaks to make it into one line

```
{{#switch}} 
{{.when Contact.Attribute.DE_NAME.FieldB == Event.my-jb-entry-event-key.FieldC}}
{{DE_FIELD}} 
{{/switch}}
```